# Is there a name for groups with presentations of the following type:  $\langle a, b \mid [b, b^{a^i}] \; (i\in \mathbb{Z}), b^{c_0}(b^a)^{c_1}\ldots (b^{a^s})^{c_s}\rangle$, (where $c_0,\ldots,c_s$ are integers)?

Tags: gr.group-theory

The presentation is a bit prettier if we set $b_i := b^{a^i}$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$:

> > > $\langle a, b \mid [b, b_i] \; (i\in \mathbb{Z}), b_0^{c_0}b_1^{c_1}\ldots b_s^{c_s}\rangle$,

Since the subgroup generated by the $b_i$ is abelian, we can even write the last relator additively as $\sum_{i=0}^s c_ib_i$.

These groups occur in a paper Derek Holt and I are writing on subgroups of finitely generated soluble groups.  They are all metabelian, and if the $c_i$ are relatively prime, they are also torsion-free.

I would like to call these groups by their proper name if they have one, especially as we have not so far managed to come up with a good name. 
Since they are fairly straightforward groups, I expect it is possible they have already come up somewhere else and been named, but unfortunately presentations are difficult to search for on MathSciNet.

EDIT:  I might as well mention our current name for these groups.  We use the notation $G(\mathbb{c})$, where $\mathbb{c} = (c_0,\ldots,c_s)$, for the group with the above presentation.  This I am happy with.  But our current name for the groups in general is `Gc-groups', which I don't like very much, and so I was hoping to find out that they already have a better name.

Comment: Presumably you've noticed that   $\langle a, b \mid [b, b_i] \; (i\in \mathbb{Z}), \rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}\wr \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Certainly!  I probably should have said, I am assuming $s\geq 1$.

Comment: I only included very minimal information about what we know about these groups, since I expect that if somebody knows what they are called, they will have seen them in at least a very similar form before.

Of course the $s\geq 1$ assumption doesn't really matter, but it cuts out the easy examples $\mathbb{Z}\wr\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_p\wr\mathbb{Z}$.  There are plenty of other 'easy' examples, though: for example if $|c_0| = |c_s| = 1$, then we get a polycyclic group.

Comment: I am not quite seeing how they can be torsion free. Since the b_i commute and some product of powers of the b_i is trivial, then the product of those b_i has finite order.

Comment: Oops, just noticed a mistake (a 'not' where there shouldn't have been one) in my reply to Tobias's comment, and then accidentally deleted it. Here is the corrected version: Not so (though you are not the first to have raised this objection). For example, $b_0b_1^{-2}=1$ only says that $b_0=b_1^2$. Why should $b_0b_1 = b_1^3$ have finite order? It's not trivial to show that these groups are torsion-free in general. The proof takes a little over a page in the current draft of our paper.

Answer (score 2):

<del>These groups are virtually wreath products of finitely generated Abelian groups with $\mathbb Z$. More precisely the subgroup $G_s=\langle a^s, b\rangle$ is a wreath product of a 1-related Abelian group (the relation is your product of powers) and $\langle a^s\rangle$, and your group is an extension of $G_s$ by a cyclic group of order $s$.</del> I do not think there exists a special name for these groups. As with every metabelian group which is Abelian-by-cyclic, you can get a lot of properties of it by looking at the corresponding $\mathbb{Z}[b,b^{-1}]$-module.

**Update.** I just realized that this group is  **not** a virtual wreath product. One can construct the group as follows. Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ and the ideal $I$.  there generated by the polynomial $f=c_0+c_1t+\ldots+c_st^s$.  The group $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the Abelian group $R/I$ by left multiplication (which are automorphisms of the additive group of $R/I$). Your group is the corresponding semidirect product $R/I\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$. One can also represent this group by $2\times 2$ matrices using the Magnus embedding. Anyway this does not answer your question about the name of the group. I still do not think it has a name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I think you are probably right that these groups have no name.  However, I'll leave the question open at least until our paper is accepted, just in case.

Comment: By the way, do you actually mean $a^{s+1}$ rather than $a^s$?  Otherwise I  don't understand what the base group in your expression of $G_s$ as a wreath product would be.

Comment: yes, it should be s+1.

Comment: @Tara: What is your paper about? Is it on the arXiv? 

Comment: The paper shows that every finitely generated soluble group which is not virtually abelian has a subgroup isomorphic to one of a small number of types (one of those being these Gc-groups).  It's called 'Finitely generated soluble groups and their subgroups', and yes, it is on the arXiv.

Comment: I know that paper, it is nice. I think your co-author probably knows the answer to your question as well as anybody else. 

Comment: @Mark:  I did suppose that Derek not knowing a name for these groups meant it was likely they didn't have one, but I thought it was still worth asking around.  I'm glad to hear that you liked the paper.  (The 'sequel', on groups with poly-context-free word problem, should be up on the arXiv next week.) 

Comment: @Tara: did you see this paper: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1009.4364 ? They study subgroups of Abelian-by-cyclic groups. 

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your edit. I had not understood why the group should be a virtual wreath product, but hadn't had time to think it through properly. Actually, it's easy to see that it is not, since for any i we have bni∈⟨b0,…,bs−1⟩ for some n. Thanks also for mentioning that paper, which I had not seen before. As far as I can tell from a brief glance through, it seems to be only about wreath products rather than Abelian-by-cyclic groups in general? Hopefully I will find some time to look at it more closely next week.

Comment: @Tara: I am not sure that wreath products (i.e. free modules) are that important there. What is important is their translation of geometric properties of the group (distortion of subgroups) into algebraic properties of polynomials. In the case of non-free modules as in your case, one would need to work with factor-rings of the ring of polynomials. It may have some applications to what you are doing. 

Comment: @Mark:  Yes, it does look interesting and possibly relevant.  

Comment: Apologies for the messed-up maths in my comment 35 minutes ago.  It should say $b_i^n\in \langle b_0,\ldots,b_{s-1}\rangle$ for some $n$.